# Bigcommerce node version error after reinstall stencil-cli

Tags: bigcommerce

The stencil gives an error info when I run $ stencil start today.

> Error info: You are using an outdated version of stencil-cli, Please run $ npm install -g bigcommerce/stencil-cli.

I reinstall the Stencil-CLI and run

```
$ npm install and $stencil start
```

> You are running an older version of node. Please upgrade to >= 4.0.0

What should  I do to resolve this problem? Can anyone help?

Comment: My computer system is win7, node version is v0.12.7

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your node version to 4.0.0 or higher and then run npm install for stencil CLI

Check out [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) installation instructions. You should then use nvm-windows to update your node to 4.X+

Comment: But in Prerequisites, they say 'Use your selected nvm tool to install version 0.12.7 (specifically) of Node.js.'

Comment: I am telling you to upgrade it because that is what the error message says and because I know we have an internal ticket to update the documentation to say as much.

Comment: Okay, I know. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `nvm use 4`.

> Now using node v4.7.3 (npm v2.15.11)

Once I ran this and tried `stencil start`, it worked for me.